# how to count rows and still display all rows? mysql

Tags: mysql

hello im trying to count the number of rows for each employee for salary.

i have two tables for ex.

**table employee**

```
id_____________name

1..............sam

2..............greg

3..............vic

4..............steve
```

**table salary**

```
id____________salary

1.............10000

1.............15000

2.............30000

3.............13000

4.............90000

4.............20000
```

**the result i need is**

```
id| name | salary| count

1 | sam  | 10000 | 2

1 | sam  | 15000 | 2

2 | greg | 30000 | 1

3 | vic  | 13000 | 1

4 |steve | 90000 | 2

4 |steve | 90000 | 2
```

to summarize: i have 4 employees with past salaries. I'm trying to create a query that shows the list of salaries and how many salaries that employee has.

here is what i have tried but i get 6 for count...

```
create temporary table rates
SELECT e.id, e.name, s.salary, count(*) as count
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN salary s ON e.id = s.id
GROUP BY name, s.salary
ORDER BY name;

create temporary table sum
select r.id, sum(count) as sum
from rates r;

select * from rates
LEFT OUTER JOIN sum s ON r.id = s.id;
```

I've tried self join but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to perform an inner join between the salary and employees tables

You also want to include a nested `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, s.salary, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM salary s
       WHERE employee_id = id) as COUNT
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN salary s ON employees.id = salary.id
```

Here is a fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b94ec/9/0

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL Server code which can give you the desired results.

```
    select 
        s.empid, e.name, s.salary,
        cnt.SalaryCount
    from 
        salary s
        inner join emp e on s.empid = e.id
        outer apply
        (select count(*) as SalaryCount from salary where empid = e.id) cnt
```